# Node.js express: confuse about router middleware

Tags: node.js, post, router

Without router middleware, once the server side receive the post data, it could log it normally:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express.createServer();
app.configure(function () {
    app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static'));
    // app.use(app.router);
    app.use(express.bodyParser());
})

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('Hello World');
});

app.post('/', function(req, res){
    console.log('body:', req.body);
    res.send(req.body);
});

app.listen(8000);
```

But once I use the `router` middleware, the log result is `undefined` and response nothing

Why? How can I solve this problem?

Comment: @freakish:I doesn't call it, I just add it but not use it

Comment: Not a good enough answer to be accepted? :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the order you called **router**

**bodyParser** must be called before **router**

```
app.configure(function () {
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/static'));
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(app.router);
});
```

Comment: Oh yeah!It success!But how can I know the order is right or not?Are there are some rules?

Comment: @hh54188 reading through official documentation is recommended.
but watch out for some changes made in Express 3.x (You can find the changes in Wiki in its Github)

Comment: Specifically, the rule is the routes are run in order. The body is set by the bodyParser middleware, so if it hasn't run, request.body won't be set.